# Does Jqplot allow for Italicized font in legend, labels, tool tips, etc?

Tags: jquery, rendering, legend, jqplot

I'm trying to add italicized text to the legend of some charts that I have being rendered through jqPlot. There isn't that much great documentation on the settings you can tweak for this but I am setting it like this in the legend:

```
        legend: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                    show: true,
                    location: 'e',
                    placement: 'outsideGrid',
                    marginRight: '50px',
                    marginBottom: '50px',
                    shrinkGrid: true,
                    fontFamily: 'Italicized',               //this line right here
                    rendererOptions: { numberColumns: 1 }
                },
```

I've tried setting it to both 'Italic' and 'Italicized' as shown above but no dice. Any ideas on if this is even supported?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation to state it's supported (I've even looked at the [enhancedLegendRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html)).

I've managed use a workaround to achieve the desired result though (this involves applying a style through CSS rather than directly through jqPlot options). The legend is rendered in a `table` that is given the class `jqplot-table-legend`. This means you can add the following CSS to apply italic font to any text within that table:

```
table.jqplot-table-legend {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqbm77j/3/) for an example.